# Did Angelina Jolie admit participating in a ritual involving sexual torture and animal sacrifice?

Tags: video, celebrities

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTdp4CvDZoc

According to this YT video:

- In 1991 Angelina Jolie was filmed when she was describing a Satanic ritual she participated in to join the Illuminati.
- The ritual involved sexual torture and animal sacrifice.
- This film leaked to the public and the YT video I linked to shows this leaked recording.

The alleged leaked recording is mixed with annotations that interpret what Angelina is shown saying. I am not asking about these annotations since I can see nothing in this video that would back up their veracity. For instance, I do not ask if the ritual was performed by the Illuminati.

However, even if one ignores the annotations, what Angelina is shown saying is disturbing enough. If the video can be trusted, Angelina seems to have admitted participating in a 'ritual' which involved beating, sexual torture similar to S&M, tattooing and the killing of a snake. She says she has 'compromising pictures' of other people, who are implied to have participated in the ritual as well. She also says she would like to 'encourage all different types of celebrities'.

Did Angelina Jolie say all of this? Did she admit she had participated in such a ritual?

Does the movie present enough evidence to back up such a claim? <sub>(possible (I guess?) weak points: it is not clear where the original, allegedly leaked recording comes from. Perhaps the original recording can be identified as something benign, but parts of it were put out of context? Also, though I'm not sure if this particular doubt is reasonable: Is the person talking indeed Angelina, or someone similar to her?)</sub>

Context: The video is linked to by conspiracy theory websites as a part of an effort to back up the claim that Hollywood is pervaded by a Satanic cabal.

Full transcript of the conversations. Words in [brackets] are those added by the video and aren't actually said:

> ANGELINA: It's like, I would, I would'be filmed it [the ritual] in
> order to encourage like everybody, all different types of celebrities.
> But there is that thing it's like... A lot of people misunderstand it
> [the ritual], maybe with S&M. And they think... It's superf[icial].
> And I have to like explain to people how... Like, where it's more
> like... You're tied down because you need to like... Be able to, like,
> have something hold you down to keep you still. Or like, you'll fight
> or go absolutely mad...
>
> [Video skip]
>
> ANGELINA: So it comes that real real place [hell]. You know, as
> opposed to being accessories or something.
>
> [Video skip]
>
> ANGELINA: It's like tattoos with me after the ritual there was that
> time where I was like 'Oh, I have tattoos' and after a while you,
> you're like, you can explain them. It comes from that real place.
>
> [Video skip]
>
> FRIEND 1: Yeah I don't know, I only saw that film she [Angelina]
> brought over that night.
>
> ANGELINA: People who are like, darker, like that kind of... you know,
> but...
>
> [Video skip]
>
> ANGELINA! It's a great thing to be able to, like, see everybody's
> sexuality, but it's so weird when you just...
>
> [Video skip]
>
> ANGELINA: I have like the most amazing compromising pictures of
> people.
>
> FRIEND 2: A 'nipple plant'. 3 whole revolutions
>
> ANGELINA: I don't remember the 3 revolutions. Like the twisting of a
> nipple?
>
> FRIEND 2: Yeah, 3 full times.
>
> FRIEND 1: I only saw that one she brought over that night though.
>
> FRIEND 2: And then the dripping candle wax on [explicit]
>
> [Video skip]
>
> ANGELINA: My snake, I tried, I had to kill him.
>
> [Video skip]
>
> [Unclear chatter]

Comment: I would have voted to close this question as not notable, but the referenced video has almost 200 thousand views. That said, the video, like most Q nonsense, is sick.

Comment: Ok, so I wrote down the whole transcript (I can edit into the question if necessary). However, she never mentions any of the words attributed to the conspiracy theory. She never says any of the following words: ritual, satanic, Illuminati, torture, sacrifice. All of those were added by the video maker. The video has 7 (!!) video skips, including some apparently large ones. If that's not some massive quote mining for out-of-context sentences, then I don't know what is.

Comment: I think that a question that requires us to comb through a lengthy, edited video and distinguish the facts from the fiction is to board too be in topic.

Comment: @Asmael Doesn't she say the word 'ritual' at min 2:01?

Comment: Has someone been watching [*Rosemary's Baby*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosemary%27s_Baby_(film))? They are all involved, everyone. Don't forget that Angelina Jolie is an actor and a director – makes movies. It seems to me that some of the crucial words she supposedly says are so indistinct they have to be imagined (such as at 2.01).

Answer (score 9):

Even if you ignore the misleading annotations, the video doesn't contain what you say it does. Jolie eg doesn't mention a 'ritual'. She does talk about sexuality & tattoos, but her interest in either is [not](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,37644,00.html) [news](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelina_Jolie#Appearance).

A [longer & less cut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjY3XzTLTH0) version of the video shows that the snipped about having to put a pet snake down is part of a larger discussion on (accidental) childhood pet deaths (starting at 4:04), not rituals. The entire video is rather dull & at no point does Jolie describe ritual torture or animal sacrifices.